# Message passing - compiler won't check whether method is existing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Objective-C's Wiki page, there is a section named [Messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C). It says when compiling, Objective-C doesn't care whether an object has a given method, because anyone can send a message to another. This is dynamic binding.

in C++, obj->method(argument); if no method, wrong.
in Objective-C, [obj method:argument]; if no method, can be fine.

But in my daily coding, with XCode, if compiler cannot find a public method of an object, it always prompt error even before build. like this,

no visible @interface for 'ClassName' declares the selector 'methodName'

I am a little confused about this 'contradiction'. Please forgive me if the question is silly. thanks in advance.

Comment: Even pre-ARC the compiler would warn if you attempted to invoke a method that was not defined.  This is, among other things, a fantastic convenience -- you know you mistyped when coding, vs having to get deeply into your test session to discover you typed x instead of s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you use ARC. For compiling ARC-enabled code, the compiler needs to know what type of objects a method expects as arguments and returns as its return value in order to be able to emit the necessary calls to memory management methods. So, when you are compiling ARC code, the compiler **will** check if a method signature exists.

If you, however, use manual reference counting (MRC), then the compiler doesn't need this information **for this purpose** (some of it is **still necessary for generating code comformant to the ABI**), and it doesn't issue an error if it can't find a certain message/method/selector. It does, however, emit a **warning** for safety.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried creating a new project without ARC and typing few test codes. Yes it will emit a warning but build can pass. [confusion setIsSolved:YES];

Comment: The compiler also needs to know the argument types without ARC. The warning means the compiler had to guess what the types are. If it guesses wrong, it will compile your code incorrectly. Fix the warning.

Comment: "The compiler doesn't need this information" is false. The compiler does need it. We would upgrade this warning into an error everywhere if we could.

Comment: @H2CO3 The compiler *does* need the information in MRC, it is just lenient about what to do when said information isn't present.  That it compiles does not mean the resulting code works.  It isn't just about the retain/release behavior, but also about the call site itself.  Without precise, unambiguous, type information, the compiler won't know which variant of `objc_msgSend()` to use, for example.   That warning always should have been a hard error, but there is far too much code out there that relies on the ambiguous behavior.

Comment: @bbum I know. I know all of this, I have written several answers asking "why declarations are needed in C". It was only a mistake in the language/wording I used that GregParker exploited to twist my words. I hope you notice the "some of it is still necessary for generating code comformant to the ABI" part in the answer!?

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler is just protecting you from yourself. In the case you note, the compiler *knows* that the method you're calling doesn't exist so it reports it as an error.

However, if you tell the compiler that you don't care or don't give it enough information, then it's perfectly valid.

Example:

```
NSString* var = @"Hello";
[(id)var thisDoesNotExist];

id var2 = @"Hello";
[var2 neitherDoesThis:var];
```

These (should) both compile.

Comment: I don't think this is **the** reason - at least not in OP's specific case. (Otherwise what you described here is true, it just doesn't fit this question well.)